# '90s/2000s book series about a "Journeyman" mage

Tags: story-identification, books, magic

Looking for a book. My main memory is that the main character is a "Journeyman" mage.

In the first book, his master tricks him and summons a demon to eat him, which he defeats. A later book has a time loop in a castle.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the check mark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I have marked your question as a Duplicate. It's not a bad question, as seen by that the details provided pointed to a clear answer, but our policy is to mark as a Duplicate confirmed answers that have the same work. :) You will still get points for upvotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debra Doyle's *[Circle of Magic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_Magic_%28Macdonald_and_Doyle_novels%29)* series as per [Fantasy book where a young prince becomes a mage](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93087/fantasy-book-where-a-young-prince-becomes-a-mage?noredirect=1&lq=1).

> The protagonist, Randal, a young boy preparing for knighthood at Castle Doun, leaves his old life behind and follows Madoc the Wayfarer, who takes him to study at the Schola Sorceriae in the city of Tarnsberg. He struggles with his studies, aided by an elder student, Nick, and comforted by a young orphan lutenist, the girl Lys. After he narrowly squeals through exams, the young and charismatic Master Laerg takes an interest in Randal, tutoring him in private; but his motives are less than honest.

In the first book, he's an apprentice. In the second book, *[Tournament and Tower](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0816718288)* (also released as *Secret of the Tower*), he has made Journeyman rank, but must undergo a quest to be allowed to use magic again.

> After breaking the oldest law in wizardry while trying to save the School of Wizardry from destruction, fifteen-year-old Randal is made a journeyman wizard but is not allowed to use his magic, no matter how great the need, until he gets permission from the wizard Balpesh living as a hermit in the far off eastern mountains.After breaking the oldest law in wizardry, journeyman wizard Randal may not use his magic until he seeks out the wizard Balpesh

The time loop book is the fifth book, *The Wizard's Castle*, mentioned [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/240561/book-series-that-follows-a-student-of-magic-who-is-expelled-after-a-teacher-is-k/240564#240564).

Comment: I would have been so annoyed if a student had squealed through exams with me.